# How to create RxSwift sequence based on selected UIButtons?

Tags: rx-swift

I am new to RxSwift.
I have 3 UIControls on the screen. Selecting one or all controls should enable the "Next" UIButton at the bottom of the screen.

I don't understand how:

1. How to create tap sequence based on UIControl's isSelected property?
2. How to update the observable model after selecting these buttons? Given that the model is immutable.
3. How to properly store/save selected values?

My model:

```
struct Model {
    let isFirstButtonSelected: Bool
    let isSecondButtonSelected: Bool
    let isThirdButtonSelected: Bool
}

let model: Observable<Model>
```

My view is configured like this:

```
func configure(_ model: Model) {
    firstButton.isSelected = model.isFirstButtonSelected
    secondButton.isSelected = model.isSecondButtonSelected
    thirdButton.isSelected = model.isThirdButtonSelected
}
```

Comment: The `rx.isSelected` property of a button is a Binder which is a type of Observer. You cannot observe an observer; you can only observe an observable.

So something in your code is causing the buttons to be selected. What is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify what causes a button to become selected in the first place. That needs to be known in order to implement a solution.

For the below, I'm going to assume that tapping on the button will toggle its selected status. The following code will track the selected status of each of the buttons and will create the `Observable<Model>`.

Comments are in the code explaining each step.

```
func example(button: UIButton, button1: UIButton, button2: UIButton, disposeBag: DisposeBag) -> Observable<Model> {
    // Put the buttons in an array to reduce code duplication.
    let buttons = [button, button1, button2]

    // Create three `Observable<Bool>`s that track the selected status of each button based on how many times it was tapped. The state is toggled from false to true then back to false...
    let selecteds = buttons.map { button in
        button.rx.tap
            .scan(false) { state, _ in !state } // toggle the state for each tap
            .startWith(false) // start with the false state
            .share(replay: 1) // save the most recent state and replay it for each subscriber.
    }

    // update the selected status of the buttons based on the above Observables. This isn't strictly necessary for the solution.
    for (button, selected) in zip(buttons, selecteds) {
        selected
            .bind(to: button.rx.isSelected)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }

    // combine the three selected statuses into an Array of Bools. Create a new Model every time one of the three statuses changes.
    return Observable.combineLatest(selecteds) { Model(isFirstButtonSelected: $0[0], isSecondButtonSelected: $0[1], isThirdButtonSelected: $0[2]) }
}
```